# Text box only digits

Tags: c#, xaml, c#-4.0, windows-8

I know this question is asked but I have another problem in my code:

```
(e.Key >= Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number0) && 
(e.Key <= Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number9)
```

It works but when I type `Shift+6` it types `&` the code wont work when shift press but after 6 is pressed it works and types as `&`.

How can I disable this? I am thinking a global variable that keeps the previous key and if it's shift don't type but it also keeps shift neither shift is pressed with a number key at the same time or shift is preesed before number key.

Comment: I feel like were only getting told half the story. What is it you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Blachshma question tag contains xaml, so I think it is WPF

Comment: @Epsil0neR WinRT has XAML too...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you `TryParse` the incomming text and see if it's `int` rather then verifying the key.

If you wish to keep the current implementation then also check for `Modifier` keys to avoid cases like `Shift+6`.

Answer (score 1):

You may as well check for special keys like `Shift`: `Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.modifierkeys.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use **PreviewTextInput**.it raises before any other textchanged or any other key event,  if you set

- **e.Handled** to True that means that all upcoming events have been handeled including (Textchanged,...), so they'll be canceled.
  if
- **e.Handeled** false so everything continues Normaly

Next you try to parse the e.text (which is the new textbox value) to an int if its true (the text is an int) e.handeled=False so the textchanged,.. continue, otherwise e.Handeled=True sothing happens

**NOTE**
on the preview event the textbox didn't changed yet, so you retrieve its value from e.Text

```
    TextBox mytextblock= new TextBox();
    mytextblock.PreviewTextInput += mytextblock_PreviewTextInput;
```

inside

```
    void mytextblock_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            int val;
            e.Handled = !int.TryParse(e.Text, out val);
        };
```

Comment: can you describe it a little more pls
in which event I am going to put these code text_Changed??

Comment: I am working on windows 8 visiual studio 12 .net 4.5 and there is no PreviewTextInput event can I use it with KeyDown Event

Comment: updated code, you sure that your **TextBox** Doesn't have a **PreviewTextInput** event, am using VS12 & .NETFX4.5 too

Answer (score 0):

better use a [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) to check if user inputed a number, as user also can paste a value which also can be valid.

Use "^\d+$" if you need to match more than one digit.

Note that "\d" will match [0-9] and other digit characters like the Eastern Arabic numerals ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩. Use "^[0-9]+$" to restrict matches to just the Arabic numerals 0 - 9.

You should check keep in private member your valid value from textbox and every time text box value is changed, you must check if value is valid, if valid, then private member = textbox.value, else textbox.value = private member, in that case you user won't be able to input not valid value

Comment: can I use regex in KeyDown event
in keyDown Event e.Key is not string and when I use .toString function returns"Number5"

Comment: in textbox_changed first types the character then code check if it fits or not if not code removes it 
what I want is user can never type a non digit character